# bubble sort in c# with array that user can input the numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

i want to make user enter the numbers and then sorted it with bubble sorting but i didn't reach to the right implementation :/

```
class bubblesort
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        int t;

        for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
        {               
            for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                {
                    t = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = a[i];
                    a[i] = t;
                }

                InputStudent(a[i]);
            }               
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Sorted array");

        foreach (int aa in a)
        {
            Console.Write(aa + " ");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void InputStudent(int p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number");

        p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static int i { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: after the user enter the numbers the output of the sorted array 
0 0 0 0 0 !

Comment: Why not ask for the #s first and then do the sort?  It doesn't really make sense to be requesting the #s in the middle of the sort.

Comment: Also, your input student function doesn't appear to be doing anything. you pass in an int, then you get an int from the user, then you do a local assignment inside the method, which goes away as soon as the method scope ends)

Comment: I'm voting to leave open. The question is poorly asked, and on its own I'd agree to close as "unclear what you're asking", but the answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the numbers from the user FIRST, then you can sort them. Right now your `InputStudent` function isn't doing anything - it just takes in an integer as a parameter, re-assigns it with a value from the user, and then exits.

You could instead do something like this to get an array of ints from the user:

```
private static int[] GetIntArrayFromUser(int numberOfElementsToGet)
{
    var intArrayFromUser = new int[numberOfElementsToGet];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElementsToGet; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Prompt user for integer and get their response
            Console.Write("Enter an integer for item #{0}: ", i + 1);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            // Check the response with int.TryParse. If it's a valid int, 
            // assign it to the current array index and  break the while loop
            int tmpInt;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out tmpInt))
            {
                intArrayFromUser[i] = tmpInt;
                break;
            }

            // If we get here, we didn't break the while loop, so the input is invalid.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid integer. Try again.", input);
        }
    }

    return intArrayFromUser;
}
```

Then you can call this method from Main to populate your array:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = GetIntArrayFromUser(5); // Get a five-element array

    // Insert your bubble-sort code here

    // Show the sorted array
    Console.WriteLine("The sorted array:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a));

    Console.Read();
}
```